# How to Pass the href value in <a> </a> tag dynamically under listview

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I stored my Redirect page Url's in database under a column named Module_img. When i try to access the column in aspx page it through the error : "Preprocerror directive expected ". Here is my code

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">  
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a href='<% #Bind("Module_Redirect") %>'> Hi </a> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Does `'<% #Eval("Module_Redirect") %>'` work?

Comment: Use a hyperlink control http://forums.asp.net/t/1261810.aspx?Dynamic+Hyperlink+in+listview

Comment: '<%# Eval("Module_Redirect")%>' worked for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with `Eval` if you remove the space between `%` and `#`:

```
<a href='<%# Eval("Module_Redirect") %>'> Hi </a>
```

Comment: ThankYou @ConnorsFan . It worked for me. Can you further guide me in How can i pass the complete Url coming from database in an html <img> tag

Comment: I think you could use the same technique: `<img src='<%# Eval("ImageUrlFieldName") %>' ...>`